# how to set up a zig tcp server socket

Tags: tcp, zig

I am learning zig and want to make a simple tcp server. have a general idea on how to do this in C. My understanding on what needs to happen is this:

1. get a File Descriptor
2. Set the options for how you want the socket to be connected.
3. Bind the File Descriptor to a socket. Setting the options for that socket (TCP, UDP, etc..)
4. Use the socket
5. Close the socket.

I Have tried looking for examples online, but most of them are too abstracted or they are HTTP protocols (which I don't want).

It seems that every one of my attempts results in a client socket rather than a server.
This is my example

```
const std = @import("std");
const print = std.debug.print;
const net = std.net;

pub fn main() void {

    print("Starting IP-Addres vendor\n", .{});
    const addr = net.Address.resolveIp("127.0.0.1", 9090) catch | err | {
        print("An error occured while resolving the IP address: {}\n", .{err});
        return; 
    };
    
    // I was hoping this would yield a server socket, but it seems to be a client
    // socket. This is where my program ends. 
    const socket = net.tcpConnectToAddress(addr) catch | err | {
        print("An error occured creating a TCP connection: {}\n", .{err});
        return; 
    };
    
    defer socket.close();

    var server = net.Server{.listen_address=addr, .stream=socket};
    print("Starting TCP server...\n", .{});    
    
    while ( net.Server.accept(&server)) | conn | {        
        print("Received a connection\n",.{} );
        conn.stream.close();
        
    } else  |err| {        
        print("An error occured while acception a connection: {}\n", .{err});
        
    }
}
```

My end goal is to have this server communicate to a client i wrote in C. The whole thing is a learning experience, that is why the mix of languages.

Thanks in advance.

I expected the socket to be a server socket that can receive connections and communicate with clients over a custom protocol. The error I get is the following:

```
An error occured creating a TCP connection: error.ConnectionRefused
```

I don't have any other processes running on that port, which tells me that the socket I tried to open was a client attempt.

zig version
0.12.0-dev.2990+31763d28c

Comment: fyi, there's a simple [tcp server example](https://zigcc.github.io/zig-cookbook/04-01-tcp-server.html) in the zig-cookbook from the [zigcc](https://github.com/zigcc).

Comment: The entire first bit of your code is for _connecting_ to a server. You just want `server.listen`. Address could just be `Address.initIp4(&.{127, 0, 0, 1}, 9090)` since you're not "resolving" anything.

Comment: thanks @FObersteiner that was what i needed. I hadn't heard of the cook book.

Comment: Glad I could spread the word :) The ziggit also has a good overview of [resources to learn](https://ziggit.dev/t/zig-learning-resources/3160).